# How does "constness" propagate through calls to overloaded operator->()?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've implemented a thread-safe wrapper for arbitrary objects that uses the drill down behavior of `operator->()`, my problem is that I don't quite understand how constness of the wrapped object is propagated through the calls to the operator->() down to the wrapped object pointer:

```
const T *operator->() const
{
    mtx_.lock();
    return const_cast<const T *>(t_);
}
```

is never called in the Protector class, even though `ThreadSafe<const std::string>` won't call a non-const method on the string it wraps, declaring it as `const ThreadSafe<const std::string>` changes nothing.

Could you explain why this is the case - the non-const version of the operator is called, but the end result is as if the const version of the operator was called.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class ThreadSafe
{
  public:
    template <class... Args>
    explicit ThreadSafe(Args &&...args)
        : obj_{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
    {
    }

    auto operator->()
    {
        return Protector(&obj_, mtx_);
    }

    auto operator->() const
    {
        return Protector(std::add_const_t<T *>(&obj_), mtx_);
    }

    //  method strictly for debugging
    T copy() const
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx_);
        return obj_;
    }

  private:
    struct Protector
    {
        explicit Protector(T *t, std::mutex &mtx)
            : mtx_(mtx)
            , t_(t)
        {
        }

        T *operator->()
        {
            mtx_.lock();
            return t_;
        }

        const T *operator->() const
        {
            mtx_.lock();
            return const_cast<const T *>(t_);
        }

        ~Protector()
        {
            mtx_.unlock();
        }

        std::mutex &mtx_;
        T *t_;
    };

    mutable std::mutex mtx_;
    T obj_;
};

int main()
{
    //  ThreadSafe<std::string> ts_i{"123456789"};
    //  ts_i->append("0");
    //  std::cout << ts_i->c_str() << std::endl;

    const ThreadSafe<const std::string> cts_i{"asd123"};
    //      cts_i->append("10"); // non const methods are inaccessible with a ThreadSafe<const T> wrapper, but const methods are.
    std::cout << cts_i->substr(3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `const_cast` isn't required there, adding a `const` qualifier can always be done implicitly.

Comment: However your locking looks useless.  It protects the read of `t_` against another class member swapping `t_` with another pointer... but I don't see any member functions capable of changing the pointer.  Are you thinking that `protector->func()` will hold the lock during the call of `func()`?  It will not.

Comment: Could you construct an example that breaks this code? I did a bit of testing and this does seem to work. put a print with a counter in the locking code after the lock and an unlocking counter in the destructor, and print something from inside the protected code. You will see a sequence of: lock1, operation on object, unlock1, lock2 operation2 unlock2...

Answer (score 0):

Both of these return the same type (non-const `Protector`), so naturally chained `operator->()` is treated the same in both cases:

```
auto operator->()
{
    return Protector(&obj_, mtx_);
}

auto operator->() const
{
    return Protector(std::add_const_t<T *>(&obj_), mtx_);
}
```

The second one wouldn't even compile if `T` is not const-qualified already.

Comment: May I ask you to add a corrected implementation of the const arrow overload in ThreadSafe and Protector classes? The implementation seems to work, though is incorrect and don't like that I don't know how to make it correct...